# MySQL ORDER BY multiple elements in different where clauses

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a question for which I do not know how exactly to call it. Maybe I just don't use the correct naming and therefore I cannot find the answer.

But the case is like this.
I have a database table with similair data to the following:

- booking_id (int)
- booking_start (Y-m-d)
- booking_starttime (H:i)
- booking_hotelstart (Y-m-d)
- booking_hotelstarttime (Y-m-d)
- booking_hotelend (Y-m-d)
- booking_hotelendtime (H:i)
- booking_end (Y-m-d)
- booking_endtime (H:i)
- booking_confirmed (bool)

Now I would like to make a query that does about this :
*(invalid query just to demonstrate what I would like)*

```
SELECT `booking_id` FROM `system_bookings` WHERE (
(`booking_start`='2014-10-20' ORDER BY `booking_starttime` ASC)
OR
(`booking_hotelstart`='2014-10-20' ORDER BY `booking_hotelstarttime` ASC)
OR
(`booking_hotelend`='2014-10-20' ORDER BY `booking_endtime` ASC)

OR
(`booking_end`='2014-10-20' ORDER BY `booking_endtime` ASC)
)
AND
`booking_confirmed` = TRUE LIMIT 0, 100
```

So basically an ORDER BY with a clause. But how to do this?? I have no clue how to correctly search for this. Hence I hope someone could show me a bit the direction I should be heading. Other than that. I would like to know how this is called. For next searches.

Thanx in advance!!!

---

*edit :*

I created some sample data as requested :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `system_bookings` (
  `booking_id` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `booking_start` date NOT NULL,
  `booking_starttime` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `booking_hotelstart` date NOT NULL,
  `booking_hotelstarttime` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `booking_hotelend` date NOT NULL,
  `booking_hotelendtime` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `booking_end` date NOT NULL,
  `booking_endtime` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `booking_confirmed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`booking_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;



INSERT INTO `system_bookings` (`booking_id`, `booking_start`, `booking_starttime`, `booking_hotelstart`, `booking_hotelstarttime`, `booking_hotelend`, `booking_hotelendtime`, `booking_end`, `booking_endtime`, `booking_confirmed`) VALUES
(1, '2014-10-09', '21:19', '2014-10-08', '21:19', '2014-10-23', '08:00', '2014-10-23', '22:00', 1),
(2, '2014-10-11', '16:00', '2014-10-27', '12:15', '2014-10-28', '17:45', '2014-10-28', '17:45', 1),
(3, '2014-10-10', '20:30', '2014-10-10', '20:30', '2014-10-11', '08:00', '2014-10-20', '14:00', 1),
(4, '2014-10-12', '20:00', '2014-10-12', '20:00', '2014-10-13', '05:00', '2014-10-29', '22:00', 0),
(5, '2014-10-22', '15:00', '2014-10-22', '20:30', '2014-10-23', '04:15', '2014-10-31', '12:00', 1);
```

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve ?

Comment: I would like to get the bookings matching the query but also ordered by the individual clauses

Comment: what you are trying to achieve from that query is not possible, multiple order by is not possible until you use a subquery. please post some sample data and desired result.

Comment: May be this help: `order by first_field asc, second_field desc, third_field asc`

Comment: Why are you splitting the `DATE` and the `TIME` values into two columns and then setting the `TIME` values to `VARCHAR`?  Surely some of the built in types would be better.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-types.html

Comment: @MichaelMcGriff I know.. but this is the way it has been build... About 6 years ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have multiple conditions in the `order by` clause.  So, formally, you seem to want this:

```
SELECT `booking_id`
FROM `system_bookings`
WHERE `booking_confirmed` = TRUE AND
       (`booking_start` = '2014-10-20' OR
        `booking_hotelstart` = '2014-10-20' OR
        `booking_hotelend`='2014-10-20' OR
        `booking_end`='2014-10-20'
       )
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN `booking_start` = '2014-10-20' THEN `booking_starttime` 
               WHEN `booking_hotelstart` = '2014-10-20' THEN `booking_hotelstarttime`
               WHEN `booking_hotelend` = '2014-10-20' THEN `booking_endtime`
               WHEN `booking_end` = '2014-10-20' THEN `booking_endtime`
          END)
LIMIT 0, 100;
```

However, this is a bit non-sensical, because you are comparing a value to a constant, and then sorting by that value.  I suspect you want to prioritize the `where` clauses and really want something more like this:

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN `booking_start` = '2014-10-20' THEN 1
               WHEN `booking_hotelstart` = '2014-10-20' THEN 2
               WHEN `booking_hotelend` = '2014-10-20' THEN 3
               WHEN `booking_end` = '2014-10-20' THEN 4
          END)
```